# The integer next above $(\sqrt3+1)^{2m}$ contains $2^x$ as a factor. Find $x$.

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, fractions, binomial-theorem

**Question**

> The integer next above $(\sqrt3+1)^{2m}$ contains $2^x$ as a factor. Find $x$.

**Attempt 1**

$(\sqrt3+1)^{2m}=(4+2\sqrt3)^m=2^m(2+\sqrt3)^m=I+f$, where $I$ is the integral value and $f$ is the fractional value of the expression.

Since $0\lt\sqrt3-1\lt1\implies0\lt(\sqrt3-1)^m\lt1$

Let $(\sqrt3-1)^m=f'$

$(\sqrt3+1)^{2m}+(\sqrt3-1)^{2m}=2^m\left((2+\sqrt3)^m+(2-\sqrt3)^m\right)=2^{m+1}(^mC_0\cdot2^m+^mC_2\cdot2^{m-2}\cdot3+...)$

LHS is $I+f+f'$. RHS is even integer. So, $I+f+f'$ is integer. And $f+f'$ can only be $1$.

So, I got $x$ as at least $m+1$.

Can we say something about the odd/even nature of $(^mC_0\cdot2^m+^mC_2\cdot2^{m-2}\cdot3+...)?$

**Attempt 2**

Let $(\sqrt3+1)^{2m}=I+f, I$ being the integral value and $f$, the fractional value.

Let $(\sqrt3-1)^{2m}=f'$, where $0\lt f'\lt1$

$(\sqrt3+1)^{2m}+(\sqrt3-1)^{2m}=I+f+f'$

LHS$=2(^{2m}C_0\cdot3^m+^{2m}C_2\cdot3^{m-1}+...+^{2m}C_{2m})$

This time, I am just getting $2^1
$ as the factor. What's wrong here?

Comment: Write a recurrence for $a_n=(\sqrt3+1)^{2m}+(-\sqrt3+1)^{2m}$ using $x^2 - 2 x - 2$, which has $\pm \sqrt3+1$ as roots.

Comment: @lhf I guess I am not aware of the method you are suggesting. Also, I have made an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your attempt 1, you wrote

> Can we say something about the odd/even nature of $(^mC_0\cdot2^m+^mC_2\cdot2^{m-2}\cdot3+...)?$

Yes, we can.

We can prove the following claims :

**Claim 1** : If $m$ is even, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac m2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2k}2^{m-2k}3^k$ is odd.

**Claim 2** : If $m$ is odd, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac m2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2k}2^{m-2k}3^k$ is of the form $2\times\text{odd}$.

(Proofs of these claims are written at the end of this answer.)

From these claims, we can say that the answer is $x=2\left\lfloor\dfrac{m+1}{2}\right\rfloor+1$.

---

In your attempt 2, you wrote

> This time, I am just getting $2^1$ as the factor. What's wrong here?

Nothing is wrong.

What you got here is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{2k}3^{m-k}$ which is different from $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac m2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2k}2^{m-2k}3^k$ which you got in your attempt 1.

---

In the following, let us prove the following two claims :

**Claim 1** : If $m$ is even, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac m2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2k}2^{m-2k}3^k$ is odd.

**Claim 2** : If $m$ is odd, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac m2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2k}2^{m-2k}3^k$ is of the form $2\times\text{odd}$.

*Proof of claim 1* :

Letting $m=2s$, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac m2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2k}2^{m-2k}3^k=\underbrace{2^{2s}+\binom{2s}{2}2^{2s-2}3^1+\cdots +\binom{2s}{2}2^{2}3^{s-1}}_{\text{even}}+3^s$$
so this is odd.$\ \blacksquare$

*Proof of claim 2* :

Letting $m=2s-1$, we have

$$\begin{align}&\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac m2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2k}2^{m-2k}3^k
\\\\&=2^{2s-1}+\binom{2s-1}{2}2^{2s-3}3^1+\cdots +\binom{2s-1}{2s-4}2^{3}3^{s-2}+(2s-1)2^{1}3^{s-1}
\\\\&=\color{red}2\bigg(\underbrace{2^{2s-2}+\binom{2s-1}{2}2^{2s-4}3^1+\cdots +\binom{2s-1}{2s-4}2^{2}3^{s-2}}_{\text{even}}+\underbrace{(2s-1)3^{s-1}}_{\text{odd}}\bigg)\end{align}$$
so this is of the form $\color{red}2\times\text{odd}$.$\ \blacksquare$

Comment: $$^mC_0\cdot2^m+^mC_2\cdot2^{m-2}\cdot3+...$$ If $m$ is even, the last term would be $^mC_m\cdot2^0\cdot(\sqrt3)^m$, which is odd, but if $m$ is odd then the last term would be $^mC_{m-1}\cdot2^1\cdot(\sqrt3)^{m-1}$, which is even. So, in this case won't we get $2^{m+2}$ as factor?

Comment: In my understanding, if $m$ is even then the answer is $m+1$; if $m$ is odd then the answer is $m+2$. Is this what you are also saying?

Comment: Is the other answer also saying the same?

Comment: @aarbee : Yes, that is what I'm saying. I wrote in this answer, "From these claims, we can say that the answer is $x=2\left\lfloor\dfrac{m+1}{2}\right\rfloor+1$" which is exactly the same as your understanding. The other answer is saying the same. However, it seems that the answer has not proved the inequality $e(m)\le e(m+1)$ which is needed to get our conclusion.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I am still not clear about Attempt 2 though. There I am just getting $2^1$ as factor but we need at least $2^{m+1}$. Inside the bracket there, the first term is odd. So, looks like no more $2's$ can come out.

Comment: @aarbee : In your attempt 2, you already got $(\sqrt3+1)^{2m}+(\sqrt3-1)^{2m}=2\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{2k}3^{m-k}$ which is correct. Now, you have to prove that if $m$ is even, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{2k}3^{m-k}$ is of the form $2^m\times\text{odd}$, and that if $m$ is odd, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{2k}3^{m-k}$ is of the form $2^{m+1}\times \text{odd}$. This should be much more difficult than attempt 1. So, I would choose the first one :) As you said, no more 2's, but as a sum, these do hold which is why these are difficult.

Comment: I think I got it. When we add $7$ and $5$, we get $2^2$ as factor. Similarly, in second attempt, when we add the odd terms we can get $2^{m+1}$ as a factor. Similarly, in first attempt, are we certain that we are only getting $2^{m+1}$ as a factor? Can the bracket term (sum of terms) not yield more $2's$? I guess we are certain here because in attempt one, it's even terms plus just one odd term which necessitates that the sum is indeed odd. So, no more $2's$. Thanks for your inputs. Means a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_m=(\sqrt3+1)^{2m}+(-\sqrt3+1)^{2m}=\alpha^m+\beta^m$, where $\alpha=(\sqrt3+1)^2$ and $\beta=(-\sqrt3+1)^2$.

Since $0 < \beta < 1$, we have $(\sqrt3+1)^{2m} < a_m < (\sqrt3+1)^{2m}+1$ and so $a_m = \lceil (\sqrt3+1)^{2m} \rceil$.

Now, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $x^2 = 8 x - 4$ and so $a_{m+2}=8a_{m+1} -4a_m$.

Write $a_m=2^{e(m)}b_m$ with $b_m$ odd. Then, $$a_{m+2}=8a_{m+1} -4a_m=2^{e(m)+2}(2^{e(m+1)-e(m)+1}b_{m+1}-b_m) \quad (*)$$ and so $e(m+2)=e(m)+2$. Therefore, $e(m)$ for $m=0,1,2,\dots$ is
$
1,3,3,5,5,7,7,\dots
$

$(*)$ provided $e(m)\le e(m+1)$, which I expect can be proved by induction.